# Selenium can't find elements until I inspect the page

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have quite a weird problem.
There's a website that has the following two buttons (I can see them when I inspect the page):

button 1

```
<ul class=" _3dEhb">
   <li class = " LH76I">
      <a class="-na14 _81NM2" href="/preview/">
         <span class="g47FY 10XF41"</span>" preview"
   <li class = " LH76I">
      <a class="-na14 _81NM2" href="/launch/">
         <span class="g47FY 10XF41"</span>" launch"
```

I'm using the python selenium code

```
buttons = driver.find_element_by_class_name('LH76I')
```

if I run it without inspecting the webpage, this code gives me an empty list.
However, if I debug and I inspect the webpage, the same code gives me 2 items in the list.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: What is your exact _Manual Step_? Which element(s) are you trying to locate? What is your next coarse of action with the elements?

Comment: @DebanjanB I get the page using driver.get() and then I would simply need to click on the "launch" button". However, even though the html code used for the "launch" button is the one shared above, I get the No Such Element exception. Also, even if I use find_elements, len(buttons) will still give me 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `driver.find_elements_by_class_name` instead because you are trying to get a list of elements with same identifier. Try the following code:

```
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('LH76I')
```

Then, if you want to click or something, you would do:

```
buttons[0].click()
```

EDIT - You can try the way the list items are generally extracted:

```
main_list = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_3dEhb') //gets the main ul element
List<WebElement> list_items = main_list.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
for x in range(0, len(list_items)):
{
    // whatever you want to do with the item
}
```

Comment: manu thanks for your answer. Same problem though if I use find_elements. If I user your code and then run len(buttons), I get 0. At that point, I usually get frustrated, I right click on the "launch" button, I click on inspect, and I see the code shared above. At that point, if I rerun my python script, i.e. buttons = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('LH76I'), it works.

Comment: could the issue be related to the <li class> indented inside a <ul class>?

Comment: can you try using try-except block to find the element again in case it fails? Is it in some kind of iframe? Since its a list, are the dropdown items only visible when you click dropdown element? Can you share the entire HTML if possible?